# "One-way synchronization" between Mail and Gmail?

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

In the past (say, with Snow Leopard, although I don't remember exactly when I set up my old client) it used to be possible to have a "one-way synchronization" between the Mail client and a gmail account in the following sense: the Mail client would download any new messages that were sent to my email, but would not notify gmail of any changes that I made locally.

The main advantage of this setup is that I could have an unofficial "cloud storage": my local client would be where I actually did my work. It would contain the emails I actually needed to respond to, and my drafts, etc.  But I could recklessly delete things locally with the knowledge that if I ever *really* needed them, even years later, I just had to log into my account online.

Is there any way to do this with El Capitan? or at least to simulate the effect somehow?

Answer (score 1):

You are describing an account set up with POP3.
To achieve that behavior follow [this instructions](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7104828?hl=en):

### First, set up POP in Gmail

- On your computer, open Gmail.
  In the top right, click Settings Settings.
- Click Settings.
- Click the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab.
- In the "POP Download" section, select Enable POP for all mail or Enable POP for mail that arrives from now on.
- At the bottom of the page, click Save Changes.
- Next, make changes on your email client
- Go to your client, like Microsoft Outlook, and check these settings.

**Incoming Mail (POP) Server**: pop.gmail.com

**Requires SSL**: Yes

**Port**: 995

**Outgoing Mail (SMTP) Server**: smtp.gmail.com

**Requires SSL**: Yes

**Requires TLS**: Yes (if available)

**Requires Authentication**: Yes

**Port for SSL**: 465

**Port for TLS/STARTTLS**: 587

If you use Gmail with your work or school account, enter mail.domain.com, then select Port 110.

**Server timeouts** Greater than 1 minute (5 is recommended)
**Full Name or Display Name**   Your name
**Account Name, User Name, or Email address**   Your email address
**Password**    Your Gmail password

When adding your account choose "Other" instead of "Gmail" on Mail app.

Comment: This works, I've been doing it for years